# Eclipse Android Runtime Errors fatal exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments

On running this Activity, I get many Runtime errors, such as `FATAL EXCEPTION: Unable to start Activity`. Can you help me understand why I'm getting these errors?

### MainActivity.java

```
package com.khulesh.extab;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener{

    ActionBar actionbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        actionbar=getActionBar();
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


        ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionbar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("tab1");
        tab1.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab2 = actionbar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("tab2");
        tab1.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab3 = actionbar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("tab3");
        tab1.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab4 = actionbar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("tab4");
        tab1.setTabListener(this);

        actionbar.addTab(tab1);
        actionbar.addTab(tab2);
        actionbar.addTab(tab3);
        actionbar.addTab(tab4);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    tools:context="com.khulesh.extab.MainActivity" />
```

### Screen shot of errors

[image: error screen shot]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem not to set any text or listener for any tab except for `tab1`. That might be it. You must have duplicated code via Copy + Paste and then you forgot to make the necessary changes.

Comment: thanks cobarzan........ That was a silly Mistake ........... Thank You very much.. Now its working